# backpack tells me the following error Call to undefined method App \ Models \ User :: identifiableAttribute () and I don't know why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

the problem I have with a backpack its the next one.
I have installed backpack in my laravel 8 project, and when generating all the crud. And it does not work correctly and it tells me the following error:

```
Call to undefined method App \ Models \ User :: identifiableAttribute ()
```

And I do not know how to solve it, I have already tried changing the relationships and other methods but it does not work
These are my models

**User model**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'url_avatar',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

And **Report model**, the report model have relation with a user and post:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;

class Report extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','post_id', 'user_reported_id','name_user','email_user','name_user_reported','email_user_reported'
    ];

    protected $table='reports';

    public func`enter code here`tion user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

This is what **Backpack generate** for me, the crud :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\ReportRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class ReportCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class ReportCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Report::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/report');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('report', 'reports');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('user_id');
        CRUD::column('post_id');
        CRUD::column('user_reported_id');
        CRUD::column('name_user');
        CRUD::column('email_user');
        CRUD::column('name_user_reported');
        CRUD::column('email_user_reported');

        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']); 
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(ReportRequest::class);

        CRUD::field('user_id');
        CRUD::field('post_id');
        CRUD::field('user_reported_id');
        CRUD::field('name_user');
        CRUD::field('email_user');
        CRUD::field('name_user_reported');
        CRUD::field('email_user_reported');

        /**
         * Fields can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::field('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addField(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number'])); 
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}
```

When i go to the secition os reports on backpack it doesn't working i the error its the next one:

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\User::identifiableAttribute() (View: D:\mydir\vendor\backpack\crud\src\resources\views\crud\columns\select.blade.php)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dHvZ.png)

Answer (score -1):

هذه الطريقة الصحيحةici

```
<!DOCTYPE><?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
class User extends Authenticatable { use HasFactory, Notifiable;
/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email', 'password', 'url_avatar', ];
/**
* The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $hidden = [ 'password', 'remember_token', ];
```

Comment: @Abdelllatif What do you mean?